# Is the config file .eslintrc deprecated in favor of .eslintrc.* files?

Tags: node.js, eslint, eslintrc

I am updating some repos and would like to migrate from 5.x to 7.x eslint. But we use the file .eslintrc in all our repos. According to eslints's [official configuration docs](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats) it seems to be deprecated, now. What format should we use instead?

I suppose `.eslintrc.js` format would be the most flexible while `.eslintrc.json` may be enough as long as we don't need any dynamic code? In the same configuration docs, the eslint team uses `.eslintrc` all the time by theirselves and I see the `.eslintrc` file a lot in other repos, too. So I am a little bit confused about how serious this deprecation really is, what is best practice, now, and what is most future proof.

Comment: To explicitly answer the question: _is the config file .eslintrc deprecated in favor of .eslintrc.* files?_ -- The answer is YES! See [**.eslintrc without file extension is deprecated**](https://dev.to/ohbarye/eslintrc-without-file-extension-is-deprecated-3ngg), and [Configuration Files - use a JavaScript, JSON, or YAML file to specify configuration information for an entire directory and all of its subdirectories.](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/#configuration-file-formats).

Comment: Well, the warning line I get includes `DeprecationWarning: '~/.eslintrc.*' config files have been deprecated` which clearly says that ANY .eslintrc file — including extensions - is deprecated. Can’t have it both ways.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is the config file `.eslintrc` deprecated in favor of `.eslintrc.*` files?

Yes, but it's still supported.

> What format should we use instead?

`.eslintrc.json` is the most similar to what you're used to, it's the same format but with an explicit JSON extension. If you'd like to avoid extra files, you can alternatively add your config to the `eslintConfig` field of `package.json`. If you need dynamic code, use `.eslintrc.js` or `.eslintrc.cjs`.

[Configuration Guide](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-file-formats)